# Active Record Inner Join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, InfoClosure and CityClosure which has a foreign key column CityClosure.info_closure_id.

I want to get all CityClosures where their InfoClosure.ReferenceDate is of a specific date range.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
city_closures = CityClosure.joins(:info_closure).where("info_closures.ReferenceDate >= ? AND info_closures.ReferenceDate <= ?", dateToQueryStart, dateToQueryEnd)
```

But I'm getting the error

```
StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'info_closures.city_closure_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `city_closures`.* FROM `city_closures` INNER JOIN `info_closures` ON `info_closures`.`city_closure_id` = `city_closures`.`id` WHERE (info_closures.ReferenceDate >= '2017-01-01' AND info_closures.ReferenceDate <= '2017-02-28')>
```

I don't know where active record is getting this info_closures.city_closure_id because InfoClosure doesn't have any connection with CityClosure, it's CityClosure that has a foreign key for InfoClosure

on the CityClosure model I do have a `has_many :info_closure`

how could I perform this query? Why is active record linking this way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a quick one, still going to post the answer so other people with the same problem can find the solution.

At the InfoClosure model I didn't had any connection with CityClosure, and the connection with InfoClosure was wrong.

So I added `has_many :city_closure`

```
class InfoClosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :local
  has_many :city_closure
end
```

and `belongs_to :info_closure`

```
class CityClosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :info_closure
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had an mistake here:

> on the CityClosure model I do have a has_many :info_closure

You can do this:

```
class InfoClosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :city_closures, dependent: :destroy
end

class CityClosure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :info_closure
end
```

And the query as:

```
city_closures = CityClosure.joins(:info_closure).where("info_closures.ReferenceDate >= ? AND info_closures.ReferenceDate <= ?", dateToQueryStart, dateToQueryEnd)
```